# Deleting temp and work folders in tomcat corrupts my installation

Tags: tomcat, liferay, temp

I am using Liferay 6.0.6 on tomcat. When redeploying my war, usual practice is to undeploy the old version of the war(by deleting), once it is complete, stop the service and delete the following folders
    ${CATALINA_HOME}/temp
    ${CATALINA_HOME}/work
    ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/Catalina

While this works fine most of the times, once in a while this corrupts the installation.
Other apps present in the webapp folder did not get deployed on startup. I end up redeploying all of them to make tomcat work again.

Anyone knows the reason or how to avoid it?

Comment: There should be some error in logs which is not allowing other apps to be deployed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sumukh,
Don't delete the Temp directory.  Some files may be contained in it that Tomcat is using.  Or try just removing the files within the temp directory, not the directory itself.